# segmentation fault inorder traversal

Tags: c++, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

i keep getting segmentation fault (core dump) because of the following lines :

```
void inOrder(){
        if(this->isNull())
            return ;
        this->left->inOrder();
        cout<<this->key<<' ';
        this->right->inOrder();
}
```

for the same input sometimes this function displays what is supposed to but in most cases just segfault.
im pretty sure its not because of isNull() function:

```
bool isNull(){
        return this->null;
    }
```

where null is a private bool initialized with true by pseudoconstructor
the whole code could be seen here: http://pastebin.com/RiiwqY3K
Thank you :).

Comment: If left or right is null, then the `left->inOrder()` or `right->inOrder()` will cause it

Comment: What happend if `left` or `right` is `NULL`?  Then you are dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: If you comment the balance call in your insert, will it help? I think there is some problem with the rotateLeft and rotateRight function. Not sure what it is. Also I don't understand why passing tree to rotateRight if not using it.

Comment: the problem is with inOrder function . if i comment it all works fine

Comment: @MarianIconaru Because you call `isNull()` within `inOrder`, what is happening is you are getting to a null pointer and then checking that null pointer if it is null. You cant do that.

Comment: Note that you don't need a function `isNull()` - you can just use `this` to test. `if(this) ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a case where there is a node (let it be the root node) which does not have a `left` child, so,

`root->left = NULL`

So, when you call `this->left->inOrder()` you are calling the function on a null pointer (dereferencing a null pointer), which is a segmentation fault!

So, you do not exactly need a `isNull` function to check, you just need to add `if` conditions before you call `inOrder` something like this ::

```
if(this->left != NULL)
    this->left->inOrder();
```

Similarly for `right` subtree. I am assuming that you are explicitly handling the case in which the root of the tree is NULL, `inOrder` is called on it from `main`, so you also put an `if` condition in the `main` (or anywhere) before calling this function.